# Discrete Sum of Function over a Region

Tags: graphics, regions, summation, geometry, polygons

I might have completely missed something in my search. I want to discretely sum over a function, $f(x_i,y_j)$ multiplied by some other function $g$ over a general region $S$.

$$\sum_{(x,y)\in S}f(x,y)g\Delta x \Delta y$$

where the region S is given, for example, by a polygon $P$.

1. For the polygon case, I know Mathematica can do this for an Integral as seen in the following example:

   `pol = Polygon[CirclePoints[4 \[Pi]/3, 6]];
   Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] pol]`

But this wont work if I try to do the same with Sum[].

I think one solution is to calculate the boundary of the polygon by hand, and then plug it into the Sum[] function. But there must be a better solution, given the complexity of the Polygon[] function?

2. What if it's a general region, for example by an inequality $f(x_i,y_j)<0$. Is there an easy way to do the sum over this region?

Thanks in advance! Any thoughts would be appreicated!

**Update:**

Henrik suggested DiscretizeRegion, it looks like it does discretize the region into triangles. But still, it won't work inside the Sum[] function.

Comment: If the region consists of a continuoum of points, your sum does not make sense at all.

Comment: Yes I was hoping there is way to discretize the region nicely...

Comment: Try `DiscretizeRegion`. But every meaningful sum would actually be only the discretization of an integral. And `NIntegrate` does the discretization automatically if needed.

Comment: Okay thanks, it looks like it does discretize the region geometrically but not computationally?... Am I missing something?

Comment: What is "it"? Yes, `DiscretizeRegion` will only discretize geometrically in to a  `MeshRegion`. `NIntgrate` approximates the integral by doing the geometric discretization under the hood.

Comment: You may want to inspect also the documentation of `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: In principle, what you said might be true but in physics, it is sometimes too computationally expensive to get an algebraic form for the integral and much easier to do sums (for example, sum over functions of eigenvectors of nxn matrices, which changes in a region)

Comment: I'll try to think about NIntegrate. Thank you